# Which header should I include for DXTrace?

Tags: directx

I can't find the header which has the DXTrace function in it.

Which should I include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should include `<DxErr.h>`

You can find out more about DirectX SDK here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Note that the legacy DirectX SDK's version of ``dxerr.lib`` is not compatible with the Universal CRT used by VS 2015, so it won't link if you are building with VS 2015. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/24/wheres-dxerr-lib/) for the workaround.

Comment: The old ``dxerr8.lib`` and ``dxerr9.lib`` were removed some time back because ``dxerr.lib`` included Direct3D 9 errors plus Direct3D 10 and 11.